# UIWebview open local webpage with Querystrings

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to open a webpage locally stored in UIWebview. Thats not a problem. But I want to open it with some GET Data in the URL. 
Right now I am using the following code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"start" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"flir/pages"]];
self.webView.delegate = self;
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

This opens start.html. But the URL I really want to open is start.html?var1=abc&var2=xyz.  How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://somepath%@?var=%@", filePath, @"bar"];
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
```